# Describe all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ containing $\langle{x-1}\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

So I know that I have to use the Correspondence Theorem to solve this question, but I have trouble interpreting the results. Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $I$ be an ideal in $R$. As I understand it, there is a bijection
$$\left\{\text{ ideals of } \frac{R}{I}\right\} \leftrightarrow\{\text{ ideals of } R \text{ containing } I\}$$
that preserves inclusion and some other things.

Now, I take $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $I = \langle{x-1}\rangle$. If we consider the quotient group $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\langle{x-1}\rangle}$, then we can think of it as $\mathbb{Z}[1]$ (if we think of the quotient group as adjoining $[x]$ and then requiring the condition that $x-1=0$), which is just $\mathbb{Z}$.

But there are a lot of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$, so what is the conclusion I am supposed to come to about the ideals in $R$ containing $I$?

Comment: The ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are easy to describe, and so it should be easy to describe the corresponding ideals of $R$.

Comment: Yeah, the thing I am a little confused about is I think I can get infinitely many ideals in the for $p\mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ is a prime, so how would I describe these ideals in the original ring?

Comment: Huh? The ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are all of the form $(a)$ for some positive integer $a$. Under your map $\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Z}$, what elements map to the ideal $(a)$ of $\mathbb{Z}$? I think you are getting distracted by their quantity. That’s irrelevant. They all look pretty much similar.

Comment: Would it be the ideals $\langle a \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? So the ideals $a\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: Do those contain $x-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $e:\mathbb{Z}[X]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $e(P)=P(1)$, $e$ is a morphism of ring, and $\ker(e)=\langle x-1\rangle$. We deduce that the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ which contain $X-1$ are the inverse image of the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ by $e$.

Such ideal is defined by an integer $n$, and is $\{P\in\mathbb{Z}[X]:P(1)$ is a multiple of $n\}$.

Comment: I think you mean “$P(1)$ is a multiple of $n$”?

Comment: exactly, I mean that

Comment: I think I understand up to the part where we want to take the inverse image of the ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ to get the corresponding ideal, so the ideals we are looking for are $\{ e^{-1}(a\mathbb{Z}) : a \in \mathbb{N}\}$? Is this the same thing in the last sentence?

Comment: yes, it is the same thing

Comment: @TsemoAristide Can you explain how $\ker e \subseteq \langle x-1 \rangle$?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, one ideal in $R$ that contains $I$ can be given by the set of polynomials that, when we plug in $x=1$ for that polynomial, evaluates to some multiple of an integer?

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be an ideal in $\mathbb Z[X]$ containing $\langle X-1 \rangle$.

Define
$$
J= I \cap \mathbb Z
$$
Show that $J$ is an ideal in $\mathbb Z$ and hence there exists some $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $J=n\mathbb Z$.

Now note that every $P(X) \in J$ can be written in the form
$$
P(X)=(X-1)Q(X)+a
$$
for some $a \in \mathbb Z$. This gives immediately that $a \in J=n \mathbb Z$.

From here, you can immediately deduce that
$$
I=\langle X-1, n\rangle 
$$

Comment: What is the motivation for defining $J$ like this?

Comment: @RichardKYu When dealing with ideals in polynomial rings, the Division Theorem is always helpful, if it can be used. In $\mathbb Z[X]$ you CAN divide by $X-1$ and the remainder is in $I$, but it is also an integer. The definition of $J$ is to consist of all remainders. Intuitivelly, you do the long division first and then define $J$, but the proof looks easier to follow in this order, in my oppinion.

Comment: I see, so $J$ is all the remainders after dividing through by $x-1$, so in some sense it represents the equivalence classes of the quotient ring? So we are saying that $J$ consists of integers, but why are we looking for $P(x) \in J$? The statement that $a\in J = n\mathbb{Z}$, where is the connection to this with the deduction of what $I$ is? I am unable to see this part.